# Is there a way to set asp-route-{value} dynamically based on model property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I want to generate anchor tag that takes all necessary information from the model.
So in Razor page view I currently have something like this:

```razor
    <a asp-page="/Reports/LastPeriod"
       asp-route-fromtime="@DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(-30).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")"
    >Last 30 days
    </a>
```

I want to refactor this anchor such that it is rendered dynamically from the model which looks this:

```cs
    public class LinkTag {
        public Title { get; set; }
        public Page { get; set; }
    }
```

Now is it possible to render `asp-route-fromtime` from the model somehow? This would mean I'd have to add key-value pairs in model that would be rendered to:
`asp-route-{key}={value}`

Eg. if I add `RouteValues` property like this:

```cs
    public class LinkTag {
        public Title { get; set; }
        public Page { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string,string> RouteValues { get; set; }
    }
```

Is there a way to dynamically map this property to collection of `asp-route-{key}={value}` attributes for `<a>` tag in razor page view?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single route value if you serialize your dictionary.

```cs
public class LinkTag
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Page { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> RouteValues = new();

    public string RouteValue
    {
        get
        {
            var serialized = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(RouteValues);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serialized))
                .Replace("+", "-").Replace("/", "_").Replace("=", ""); // URL safe Base64
        }
        set
        {
            int len = value.Length;
            // Restore padding and convert to standard Base64
            var base64Encoded = value.Replace("_", "/").Replace("-", "+") + new string('=', (4 - len % 4) % 4);
            var serialized = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Encoded);
            RouteValues = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(serialized) ?? new();
        }
    }
}
```